# Lanczos method to tridagonalize a matrix

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, compile

I want to tridagonalize a sparse matrix using [the Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm).
I am working with a very large sparse matrix and I need some speed. In the following for example `H=SparseArray[#->RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I}]&/@RandomInteger[{1,1000000},{5000000,2}]]// (# + #\[ConjugateTranspose])/2 &;` is my sparse matrix. I cannot use Compail as my code include a sparse array. Is there any way to speed up the code?

```
abGenerator[niter_] := 
 Module[{ket0, ket1, ketm, ketk, alist, blist},
  ket0 =Normalize@RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I},Length@H];
  alist = Table[0, niter];
  blist = Table[0, niter];
  ketk = H.ket0;
  alist[[1]] = ket0\[Conjugate].ketk;
  ket1 = ketk - alist[[1]] ket0;
  blist[[1]] = Norm@ket1;
  ket1 = ket1/blist[[1]];
  Do[
   ketm = ket0;
   ket0 = ket1;
   ketk = H.ket0;
   alist[[i]] = ket0\[Conjugate].ketk;
   ket1 = ketk - alist[[i]] ket0 - blist[[i - 1]]\[Conjugate] ketm;
   blist[[i]] = Norm@ket1;
   ket1 = ket1/blist[[i]];, {i, 2, niter}];
  {alist,
   blist}]
abGenerator[100]//AbsoluteTiming
```

For me, this takes around 16.28 seconds!
Note that I don't need this code for diagonalization and I need it for other purposes!

**Update:**

For confirmation consider the following matrix,

```
H = SparseArray[# -> RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}] & /@ 
 RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {50000, 
   2}]] // (# + #\[ConjugateTranspose])/2 &;
```

Now I can find its eigenvalue using `Eigenvalue`

```
Eigenvalues[H, 3, Method -> "Arnoldi"]
```

Which for me it gives [each run is different because the H is different!]

```
{-2.7889, 2.78153, 2.76776}
```

However, I can get the same result if I reconstruct the three-diagonal matrix and get its eigenvalue!

```
    Eigenvalues[
 abGenerator[100] // 
  DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@#[[1]]] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@#[[2, 1 ;; -2]], 1] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@#[[2, 1 ;; -2]]\[Conjugate], -1] &, 3]
```

which gives,

```
{-2.7889, 2.78153, 2.76776}
```

Comment: How we know that your code doing right job?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, you are right. I update my question!

Comment: Now it is good looking post (+1). Nevertheless, you question is not so clear, since you mentioned  that  you don't need this code for diagonalization and you need it for other purposes. What are these purposes for?

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTrounev Actually this code is used for obtaining Green Function.

Comment: Could your show an example of Green function computed with this code?

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev you can find detail in this paper: RKKY interaction in graphene bubbles https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.99.245410

Comment: We can't speed up or improve this code using paper you sited. Please, provide an attempt to compute  Green function to understand why you can't use `Compile`.